# Desktop shortcut icons all changed to Notepad icons

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons

All of my desktop shortcut icons on Windows 7 have changed to Notepad icons.

How do I get my old icons back?

Comment: What did you just install? Do you have a virus? What changed on your system?

Comment: Try restoring to a restore point. Seems some spyware attack on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Reset the desktop icon cache

1. Click Start, and open Computer.
2. On the Tool bar, click Organize and choose Folder and Search Options.
3. Click the View tab, and check to select the Show hidden files and folders option, and click OK.
4. Then, enter the following directory:

C:\Users(User Name)\AppData\Local

1. Find the IconCache.db file, and rename it as IconCache.db.old.
2. Close the window, and restart the computer.

Comment: For the record: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and quickest way I found is on 
[this forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/undo-file-association-for-lnk-extension-to/f13b105e-8ea3-47e4-aeda-66f8fc1e839d?rtAction=1401615592302).

This simply says to delete all the keys for **.lnk** extension. The procedure is:

- Press *[Win + R]* to open *run* and then type `regedit` and hit *ENTER*
- Go to the **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.lnk** folder
- Remove every subfolder (called *keys* in *regedit*) and the keys they contain
- Now restart the PC

Now everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't need to restart the PC, just restarting explorer worked.

Comment: For the record: This didn't work for me.

Comment: in many case exe files cant run. also you cant run regedit exe by cmd or any other solution. just you can create new users and move all documents there an after days delete your old user

Answer (score 0):

Download and Run the batch file [from this location](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/274775d1372780091-icon-cache-rebuild-rebuild_icon_cache.bat)
Follow the instructions in the command prompt to rebuild the Icon Cache.
Restart your computer to generate a new IconCache.db file.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the icon that is appearing in wrong format.
(You need to find out the file location that is wrong.)
This will help if all your icons have changed to Notepad, Adobe or whatever.
The file location will say either `.lnk`, `.exe`, `.jpeg` and so on.
This is called a registry error.

Here's how to fix it.

- Click the start button on the bottom left of the computer screen.
- Type `regedit` in the search box.
- Click yes if it pops up.
- then go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

  - Software -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Current Version -> Explorer -> File Exts
- Then, find what extension all your icons are showing up as, whether its `.lnk`, `.exe` and double click on it.
- Right click `User Choice` then delete it.
- Click yes.
- You will need to restart your computer and then
  all of your icons will be back to normal.

Comment: Please edit your question to **not** use **ALL CAPITAL LETTERS**

Comment: For the record: This didn't work for me.